# can we have list style type of a list a green color dot?

Tags: html, css

Can we do list style type of a list a green color dot?

My restrictions are i do not want to use list style image and i cannot edit the html in unordered list.

Comment: can you use background image. if so background:url("...") 0px 6px(adjust top-bottom and left right pixels) no-repeat; and give padding:0px 0px 0px 10px .

Comment: The problem is that i am writing a print.css file. In IE there is a browser setting to not to print background images. But i want to somehow show the bullets (green) and ofcourse without images.

Comment: Can you add a representation of your current HTML/CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I would say not to worry about color when it comes to a print stylesheet.  Many, many people print *without* color.

Comment: Yes Jason i agree with you. But wanted to give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An update of naveen's answer, with the bullet character to get a better render.

```
ul#mylist{
    list-style-type: square;
}
ul#mylist li:before{
    content: "•";
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

I'm wondering if this one is legal, as the code contains a special character.

Antoine

Comment: &bull; is an HTML entity http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/reference/entity/index.php so yes it is

Answer (score 5):

here check this out
Html:

```
<ul>
<li><span>1</span></li>
<li><span>2</span></li>
<li><span>3</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;
padding:0px;
}
ul li {
color:green;
}
ul li span{
color:blue;
}
```

Click here : http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/yYkC4/

Comment: +1 for nice [and working](http://jsfiddle.net/2zK4e/) trick sorry for another jsFiddle, didn't see you added your own :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use jQuery to manipulate the HTML.

Assuming HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{margin:20px; list-style-type:disc; color:green;}
li span{color:black;}
```

script

```
$('#list li').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<li><span>' + $(this).text() + '</span></li>');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/wTkQv/1/

Comment: +1: on an unrelated side note, you could use wrapInner instead of replaceWith. `$(this).wrapInner('<span />');`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Im not the smartest in the world but this is my way for this problem :

```
<ul>
<li><p style="color:#4ec3f4; float:left;">&bull;</p>tadam bss</li>
</ul>
```

- No javascript,
- no jQuery,
- no css tricks/hack
- agree with wc3

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly hack using `:before`

```
ul#mylist{
    list-style-type: square;
}
ul#mylist li:before{
    content: ".";
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/MSTvs/

Comment: is :before supported in ie7 i think its a part of css3?

Comment: @sushil pseudo elements are IE8+, so no, :before is not supported in IE7